# turn line dictionaries into hiearchy js

Tags: javascript

I have an array d that has dictionary items stores as such:

```
d[0] = { make: 'Audi', maxspeed: '150'}
d[1] = { make: 'VW',  maxspeed: '130'}
d[2] = { make: 'Audi', maxspeed: '180'}
d[3] = { make: 'Mercedes',  maxspeed: '150'}
d[4] = { make: 'VW',maxspeed: '170'}
```

And want to merge them to get

```
dict = [{ make: 'Audi',
      maxspeed: [150,180]
    }, 
    { make: 'VW',
      maxspeed: [130,170]
    },
     { make: 'Mercedes',
      maxspeed: [150]
    }]
```

Any suggestions for the best way to go about this? (sorry about the maxspeeds I just came up with them.)

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please attempt the problem before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()` and `reduce()` and return array as result.

```js
var d = []
d[0] = { make: 'Audi', maxspeed: '150'}
d[1] = { make: 'VW',  maxspeed: '130'}
d[2] = { make: 'Audi', maxspeed: '180'}
d[3] = { make: 'Mercedes',  maxspeed: '150'}
d[4] = { make: 'VW',maxspeed: '170'}

var result = Object.values(d.reduce(function(r, {make, maxspeed}) {
  if(!r[make]) r[make] = {make, maxspeed: [maxspeed]}
  else r[make].maxspeed.push(maxspeed)
  return r;
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Please don't encourage gimme-teh-codez questions. It encourages bad behavior and low quality questions.